# Gradle: Compile Dependencies

Tags: spring, mongodb, gradle, spring-boot

I'm using mongodb with Spring Boot. Recently, my mongodb was upgraded to version 3.0.

I'm using the following Gradle dependencies for Spring:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
}
```

If I look on maven repositories for Gradle: `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:1.2.6.RELEASE'`, I see the following (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.2.6.RELEASE):

[image: maven]

The dependencies for the mongo-java-drivers are 2.12.5 under the "Version" column. I was wondering what the "Update" column is there for and how can I use the version of the mongo-java-drivers listed there instead (3.0.4)?

Since I'm using mongo 3.0, I would like to use the 3.0.4 java-drivers instead of 2.12.5 as I need to update my java-drivers to be at least 2.13 before they will work with my mongodb 3.0: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following dependency to your project dependencies:

`compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.4'`

This will explicitly set there mongodb Java driver to the newest version and will overrun the transitive dependency version of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`.

BTW, the "Updates" column means the newest version for a specific Artifact.

Comment: Thanks orid - I tested this last night and it appeared to work as it authenticated but then it gave me some random error that i'm trying to fix. I will get back to you once i spend some more time on this.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution and it works. I was wondering if it is safe to override the transitive dependencies? If the version is listed under the update column, does that mean it is safe to use?

Comment: It is safe, but sometimes backward compatibilty may break

Answer (score 0):

You can force the usage of a newer version of a dependency by just explicitly adding the dependency version that you want to use in the pom.xml.
Then Maven will use the explicitly specified version to compile.

FYI, you can exclude a dependency triggered by a direct dependency by using the **exclude** element.

See [this doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to know how maven manages dependencies.

If you are using Gradle, see [this page](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119). In fact, you exclude the MongoDB transitive dependency triggered by spring boot and you explicitly add the latest version as a direct dependency.

Comment: Hello, sorry - I don't think I expressed myself correctly in my question. I have edited it a little bit. I'm using gradle as my built engine and not maven. I only looked up the compile dependencies on maven repository as that was the only way I knew how to identify the dependencies used in the springboot mongodb package. Can you please give me a gradle code example of how I can force gradle to take on the newer version of the dependency?

Comment: @Simon I just added a page link for Gradle, try it and tell me if it works :)